# AnimatedList is not containing initial data which is loaded using SharedPreferences

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I have an AnimatedList whose initial items are getting added before loading data from SharedPreferences. Is there a way, I can load data from device first and then build the screen.

Let's say I'm loading data into `myList` by *for loop* using SharedPreferences. And then using the data from `myList` to create AnimatedList. The problem I'm facing is, the data that was loaded is not Showing in AnimatedList. AnimatedList is getting build before loading the data.

```html
import 'package:material_todo/index.dart';

class TaskScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  TaskScreen({this.taskProvider});

  final TaskProvider taskProvider;

  @override
  _TaskScreenState createState() => _TaskScreenState();
}

class _TaskScreenState extends State<TaskScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.taskProvider.initialiseController(this);
  }

  String taskRemaining(List tasks) {
    var remain = 0;
    for (var i in tasks) {
      if (i[2] == false) {
        remain += 1;
      }
    }
    return '$remain';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: kWhiteColor,
      appBar: widget.taskProvider.editTask
          ? AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
              title: Text('Edit mode'),
              centerTitle: false,
              leading: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  widget.taskProvider.selectTask(false);
                  widget.taskProvider.toggleAddTask(false);
                  widget.taskProvider.toggleEditTask(false);
                },
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.close,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              actions: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    widget.taskProvider.editingTask();
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.edit,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    widget.taskProvider.deleteTask();
                    widget.taskProvider.toggleEditTask(false);
                    widget.taskProvider.toggleAddTask(false);
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.delete,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          : AppBar(
              title: Text(
                'Tasks',
              ),
              actions: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
//                    Navigator.of(context).push(
//                      MaterialPageRoute(
//                        builder: (context) =>
//                            SettingsScreen(provider: taskProvider),
//                      ),
//                    );
                    widget.taskProvider.clearData();
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.settings,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          if (widget.taskProvider.showAddTask) {
            widget.taskProvider.toggleAddTask(false);
          } else {
            widget.taskProvider.toggleAddTask(true);
          }
          try {
            widget.taskProvider.selectTask(false);
            widget.taskProvider.toggleEditTask(false);
          } catch (e) {
            print(e);
          }
        },
        child: RotationTransition(
          turns: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 0.125)
              .animate(widget.taskProvider.rotationalController),
          child: Icon(
            Icons.add,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            widget.taskProvider.showAddTask
                ? BuildTaskInput(widget.taskProvider)
                : Container(
                    height: 0,
                    width: 0,
                  ),
            Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, top: 30.0, bottom: 20.0),
              child: Text(
                taskRemaining(widget.taskProvider.tasks) + ' tasks remaining',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  color: Colors.grey[800],
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: AnimatedList(
                  key: widget.taskProvider.listKey,
                  initialItemCount: widget.taskProvider.tasks.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
                    return SizeTransition(
                      sizeFactor: animation,
                      child: TaskTile(
                        title: widget.taskProvider.tasks[index][0],
                        due: widget.taskProvider.tasks[index][1],
                        isChecked: widget.taskProvider.tasks[index][2],
                        isSelected: widget.taskProvider.tasks[index][3],
                        changeValue: (newValue) {
                          widget.taskProvider.checkTask(newValue, index);
                        },
                        editTask: () {
                          widget.taskProvider.setTileIndex(index);
                          widget.taskProvider.selectTask(true);
                          widget.taskProvider.toggleEditTask(true);
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```html
import 'package:material_todo/index.dart';

class TaskProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  TaskProvider() {
    loadData();
  }

  //Properties

  TextEditingController _textController = TextEditingController();
  AnimationController _rotationController;
  final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> _listKey = GlobalKey();

  int _tileIndex = 0; //index of selected tile.
  bool _showAddTask = false; //whether to show add task container.
  bool _editTask = false; // edit task.
  bool _deleteCheckTasks = false;
  bool _bottomCheckTasks = true;
  List<List> _tasks = [
    ['abc', 'Today', false, false]
  ]; //stores all the task data.

  //Getters

  List<List> get tasks => _tasks;
  bool get showAddTask => _showAddTask;
  bool get editTask => _editTask;
  bool get deleteCheckTasks => _deleteCheckTasks;
  bool get bottomCheckTasks => _bottomCheckTasks;
  int get tileIndex => _tileIndex;
  TextEditingController get textController => _textController;
  AnimationController get rotationalController => _rotationController;
  GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> get listKey => _listKey;

  //Setters

  void setTileIndex(int index) {
    _tileIndex = index;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void addTask(String title, String due) {
    int index = addTaskAtProperIndex(due);
    _tasks.insert(index, [
      title,
      due,
      false,
      false,
    ]);
    _listKey.currentState.insertItem(index);
    notifyListeners();
    saveData();
  }

  void toggleAddTask(bool value) {
    _showAddTask = value;
    if (!value) {
      _rotationController.reverse();
      _textController.clear();
    } else {
      _rotationController.forward();
    }
    notifyListeners();
    print(value);
  }

  void toggleEditTask(bool value) {
    _editTask = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void toggleDeleteTask(bool value) {
    _deleteCheckTasks = value;
    if (value) {
      for (int i = _tasks.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (_tasks[i][2] == true) {
          _tasks.removeAt(i);
        }
      }
    }
    notifyListeners();
    saveData();
  }

  void toggleBottomCheckTask(bool value) {
    _bottomCheckTasks = value;
    if (value) {
      for (int i = _tasks.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (_tasks[i][2] == true) {
          _tasks.add(_tasks[i]);
          _tasks.removeAt(i);
        }
      }
    }
    notifyListeners();
    saveData();
  }

  void checkTask(bool value, int index) {
    _tasks[index][2] = value;

    if (value && _deleteCheckTasks) {
      deleteTask();
    }

    if (value && _bottomCheckTasks) {
      _tasks.add(_tasks[index]);
      _tasks.removeAt(index);
    }
    notifyListeners();
    saveData();
  }

  void selectTask(bool value) {
    _tasks[_tileIndex][3] = value;
    notifyListeners();
    saveData();
  }

  void deleteTask() {
    _tasks.removeAt(_tileIndex);
    notifyListeners();
    saveData();
  }

  void replaceTask(String title, String due) {
    _tasks.removeAt(_tileIndex);
    addTask(title, due);
    selectTask(false);
    toggleEditTask(false);
    notifyListeners();
    saveData();
  }

  void editingTask() {
    toggleAddTask(true);
    _textController.value = TextEditingValue(text: _tasks[_tileIndex][0]);
  }

  int addTaskAtProperIndex(String due) {
    for (int i = 0; i < _tasks.length; i++) {
      if (_tasks[i][1] == due) {
        return i;
      }
      if (due == 'Today') {
        return 0;
      }
      if (due == 'Tomorrow') {
        for (int i = _tasks.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          if (_tasks[i][1] == 'Today') {
            return i + 1;
          }
        }
        return 0;
      }
      if (due == 'Anytime') {
        for (int i = _tasks.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          if (_tasks[i][1] == 'Tomorrow') {
            return i + 1;
          }
        }
        for (int i = _tasks.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          if (_tasks[i][1] == 'Today') {
            return i + 1;
          }
        }
        return 0;
      }
    }
    return 0;
  }

  void initialiseController(TickerProvider ticker) {
    _rotationController = AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200), vsync: ticker);
  }

  void saveData() async {
    SharedPreferences _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _prefs.setInt('count', _tasks.length);
    _prefs.setBool('deleteCheckTasks', _deleteCheckTasks);
    _prefs.setBool('bottomCheckTasks', _bottomCheckTasks);
    for (int i = 0; i < _tasks.length; i++) {
      _prefs.setString('$i 0', _tasks[i][0]);
      _prefs.setString('$i 1', _tasks[i][1]);
      _prefs.setBool('$i 2', _tasks[i][2]);
    }
    print('data saved successfully');
  }

  Future loadData() async {
    SharedPreferences _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var _count = _prefs.getInt('count');

    if (_count != null) {
      for (int i = 0; i < _count; i++) {
        var _title = _prefs.getString('$i 0');
        var _due = _prefs.getString('$i 1');
        var _check = _prefs.getBool('$i 2');
        _tasks.add([_title, _due, _check, false]);
      }
      print('dada loaded successfully');
    } else {
      print('No data was found');
    }

    if (_prefs.getBool('deleteCheckTasks') != null) {
      _deleteCheckTasks = _prefs.getBool('deleteCheckTasks');
    }

    if (_prefs.getBool('bottomCheckTasks') != null) {
      _bottomCheckTasks = _prefs.getBool('bottomCheckTasks');
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future clearData() async {
    SharedPreferences _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _prefs.clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: can you provide code please

Comment: I've added it. @wcyankees424

Comment: have you tried wrapping your AnimatedList in a FutureBuilder and then using your loadData() as the future

Comment: @wcyankees424 It worked thanks.

Comment: I solved it using FutureBuilder. Here is the code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55213527/flutter-set-startup-page-based-on-shared-preference/55213774

Comment: glad you fixed it :)